# ¿como sumar una columna con diferente id?

Tags: sql-server

```
CodigoAlumno IdMateria Calif
50                1       8
50                1       9 
50                3       10
60                1       6
60                2       10
70                1       6
70                2       7
70                3       8

Lo que necesito es

CodigoAlumno  SUMCalif
50                27
60                16      
70                23
```

Intente así, pero separa primero CodigoAlumno, luego IdMateria y quiero que lo sume sin importar el idMateria solo con la condicion de CodigoAlumno

```
Select F.Cod_alum, F.Nombre, sum(M.Calif) as sumCalif, 
From dbo.Alumnos F
Left Join dbo.Materias M
on  F.Cod_alum = M.Cod_alum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tenes que hacer es un group by.

Directamente agrupas por el campo que queres sumar, y sumas los otros.

```
Select M.Cod_alum, f.nombre sum(M.Calif) as sumCalif, 
From dbo.Materias M
inner join dbo.Alumnos F on m.cod_alum = f.cod_alum
group by m.Cod_alum, f.nombre
```